# What does ps h -fwC do?

Tags: linux, shell, process, command

How can I understand this part of script? Invoking `ps h -fwC ifmFuseHandler` gives this output:

```
DRBimg:/tmp # ps h -fwC ifmFuseHandler
insite1  29149     1  0 11:57 ?        Ssl    0:00 ifmFuseHandler -o allow_other /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount
```

I am particularly interested in what condition the ifmFuseHandler starts?

Here is the complete script (some excerpt form):

```
 # START IFM
        if [ $MYTYPE = "ifmFuseHandler" -o $MYTYPE = "ALL" ]
        then
            # IF A PROXY
            if [ $PROXY -eq 0 -a $DOIFM -eq 1 ]
            then
                # Make sure the fuse module is loaded
                FUSE=`lsmod | grep fuse`
                ret=$?
                if [ $ret -ne 0 ]
                then
                        /sbin/modprobe fuse 2>/dev/null
                fi
                FOUND=1
                #PID=`df | awk '/ifmFuseHandler/ {print $1}'`
                #PID=`ps -ef | grep -v 'awk' | awk '/ifmFuseHandler/ { print$2 }'`
                PID=`ps h -fwC ifmFuseHandler | awk '/ifmFuseHandler/ { print$2 }'`
                if [ "x$PID" = x ]; then
                    msg "Starting ifmFuseHandler..." $MSG_ALL
                    su - $USER -c "cd $DIR_INDEX;ifmFuseHandler  $IFM_SINGLE_THREAD -o allow_other $IFM_MOUNT"
                else
                    msg "ifmFuseHandler already running! PID=$PID" $MSG_ALL
                fi
            fi
        fi
```

Comment: location of the executable means nothing - `ps` tells you `process status` - I've found `man ps` will answer all questions you have.

Comment: nope it doesn't. I know what ps does, but not sure how ifmFuseHandler is starting, and based on what arguments of it.

Comment: In between, i have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's just using ps's -C option. Compare

```
ps h -fwC ifmFuseHandler
```

with

```
ps h -fw
```

in a shell.

Comment: Why not to use `ps -ef | grep ifmFuseHandler`? In between what is the "h" for? Sorry if i sound dumb.

Comment: Seriously, read the man page, it's all in there. In this case, no difference because it's just the pid that is extracted, but the two sets of options return some different information.

Answer (score 1):

```
PID=`ps h -fwC ifmFuseHandler | awk '/ifmFuseHandler/ { print$2 }'`
```

gives you the PID of ifmFuseHandler

```
if [ "x$PID" = x ]; then
```

tests whether a PID was returned; if not, the ifmFuseHandler is started, otherwise the message is printed that it is already running

myself, I would run

```
PID = `ps -el|grep -v grep|grep ifmFuseHandler|awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: Can you let me know the reason for not using something simple like: `ps -ef | grep ifmFuseHandler` ? What is the `h` stands for?

Comment: See the last line of my post - much simpler (also, you really have to read the man page for ps, all your questions are answered there....)

Comment: @KevinDTimm You could save all those pipes with `ps h -C ifmFuseHandler --format "%p"`... `h` for header-less output, `-C arg` to restrict the search, and `--format "%p"` to print only the PID...

Comment: @twalberg - yep, but I'm old school unix (30 yrs +/-) and so my fingers sometimes type things from rote :)  However, I did learn something about `ps` today, thanks to you and the OP.

Comment: @KevinDTimm derp... and here I thought I was old-school at a mere 27 years... ;-P

Comment: @twalberg: i wish you could also have given an answer for me to gracefully accept